# ListView - Each of Whose View Contains Multiple Components?

Tags: android, listview

[image]

I want to have my settings look like the above screenshot.

Is `ListView` used? (I am not sure... I am very new to Android...)

And Each `View` seems to have at least 2 `TextView`s.
(The first `TextView` states the name of Option and the other `TextView` describes the detail in smaller fonts.)

Two `TextView`s seem to be combines because I cannot click each of them but click the whole box.

How can I achieve this appearance?

Comment: I suggest you use `RecyclerView`. you can have items that are supported by multiple components.

Comment: To achieve this you need to use ExpandableListView.

Comment: @kimkevin Thank you so much! I couldn't find the name of `RecyclerView`!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So much thanks for @kimkevin,

I could search tutorials about `RecyclerView`.

I followed [this turial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/).